# Torsion elements of a module not a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider $A$ a ring, $M$ an A-module, and $Tor(M)$ being the set of torsion elements of M (that is, the set of $m \in M$ for which $am=0$ for some $a \in A\backslash \{0\}$ )

Show that $Tor(M)$ need not be a submodule of $M$ if $A$ is not an integral domain.

Apparently I should be considering A as a module over itself, but I don't know what that means. Would a simple counterexample suffice? And if so, is there one?

Comment: If $A$ is a ring, then there is a canonical way of considering $M=A$ as an $A$-module. You should certainly review this...

Comment: Unfortunately, my course skipped module theory and so I only have a limited knowledge of it. Is there a good resource for this kind of thing?

Comment: Any textbook which covers modules.

Comment: If you know the definition of a module it should not be very hard to understand how a ring is a module over itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ring is a module over itself using the standard multiplication in the ring.  Consider the ring $R$ of functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  Then in $R$ a function $f$ is torsion iff it has a zero.  But the sum of a function $f$ with a zero at $0$ and a function $g$ with a zero at $1$ need not have any zero, hence need not be torsion.

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathbf{Z} / 6 \mathbf{Z}$-module $\mathbf{Z} / 6\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: I'm curious to know the reason for which this has been downvoted...

Comment: Probably because it used to say Z/4Z.  In any case I gave you an upvote since you fixed the answer.  (I was not the original downvoter)